# How to retrieve pages details from woocommerce using REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I try to retrieve the pages using Woocommerce API in PHP

```
$WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
       url: 'http://example.com',
       consumerKey: 'ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       consumerSecret: 'cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
       wpAPI: true,
       version: 'wc/v1'});
```

I can get the product, order, post but I not able to retrieve the page details.

```
$woocommerce->get('products');$woocommerce->get('order');
```

But I not able to get the pages I tried to like this

```
$woocommerce->get('page'); and $woocommerce->get('pages');
```

Can any one help on this

Comment: Which pages ? If you want pages of WordPress, it's another endpoint : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: I need to get all pages in wordpress.I Can get by this endpoint GET /wp/v2/pages but I need to access in Laravel application so i need like this $woocommerce->get('pages');